# Smallest possible spinning clock?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time, rotation

The earth's rotation acts as a clock and defines a rather precise unit of time called the day. 
We could go out in outer space and spin a marble and get a reasonable clock.
On the other hand, it is my understanding that you can't do this with an electron, 
that is, you can't start an electron spinning  and then tell time by looking at the electron.
Is this correct? Assuming it is, what is the smallest object you can use as your “spinning marble” ?
I speculate that an atom of tri-substituted methane, ie CHFClBr or flouro chloro bromo methane would work.  What about a proton with its 3 quarks ?

In short, what object qualifies as the smallest possible spinning clock ?

Comment: The Earth's rotation is actually a surprisingly imprecise way of defining a unit of time. There's an international organisation - the Earth Rotation Service - dedicated to tasks such as reconciling atomic time with mean solar time. *"The length of a solar day varies throughout the year, and the accumulated effect of these variations (equation of time) produces seasonal deviations of up to 16 minutes."*

Comment: it cannot be certainly smaller than order h

Comment: @brucesmitherson The *angular momentum of the system* can't be smaller than order $h$, but that doesn't really answer the question about how big the system has to be. I suspect that you need a system big enough to reliably behave classically; because it needs to have a defined angular orientation at all times.

Comment: @McKee  and@ brucesmitherson
Ah yes that is a good point.  Suppose I now say I want a spinning clock with angular momenhtum exactly h-bar.  At least in principle it could be an object as large as the earth, just spinning very slowly.  This system would surely act quasi-classically and would work as a clock except for the fact that it would rotate so slowly it would be hard to detect the motion.

Comment: Back to something like my original question: For fixed angular momentum (ie h-bar), the angular velocity is inversely proportional to the moment of inertia, of course. Therefore, you would want the spinning object's moment of inertia to be small enough that the rotation would be reasonably noticeable, but large enough that the object still behaves in a nearly classical manner.  How big is that? AZgain, my guess is bigger than an electron, but smaller than a small molecule.  Or is that too optimistic?

Comment: @dmckee  sorry I messed up the notifications above. Can you confirm that an electron does not work? How about a hydrogen atom? A hydrogen molecule? I think a small molecule like H2 or H2O might work in principle, if not in practice.

Comment: Jim, if I knew the answer I would post it. The above is slightly informed spittballing. If it helps fine. If it is wrong than ignore it, but that is all I have.

Comment: An interesting side-note here is that NMS depends on the clock-like *precession* of nuclear magnetic moments in a strong field. But I believe that as a practical instrumental matter you have to interrogate a very large number of atoms at once.

Comment: I guess a H2 molecule should do it (in principe, if not in practice, as you say).

Comment: It depends on your definition of spinning. In some sense the electrons in an atom are spinning around the atomic nucleus. Then the definition of a second would depend on quantum transitions of such a spinning clock.